# Как сделать скриншот главной страницы сайта?

Tags: php

Как сделать скриншот главной страницы сайта не используя никакие сторонние сервисы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. запустить виртуальную машину с нужной ОС и браузером, выполнить скрипт, который зайдёт на нужный сайт и сделает скриншот — так работают сервисы по оскриншочиванию во всех моделях браузеров, включая вымершие версии;
2. Adobe Air простое приложение, в нём банально компонент браузера, и снятие копии его же экрана в файл.

Answer (score 1):

Хочется посоветовать PhantomJS. Это запуск полноценного движка WebKit из консоли, то есть все будет отображаться и работать, как в обычном браузере.
Из php можно вызвать его через exec, а значит это полностью программное решение без сторонних сервисов.

Пример взят из http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/116789/

Запуск в консоли так:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html clock.png
```

Код создания скриншота:

```
if (phantom.state.length === 0) {
    if (phantom.args.length !== 2) {
        console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        var address = phantom.args[0];
        phantom.state = 'rasterize';
        phantom.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
        phantom.open(address);
    }
} else {
    var output = phantom.args[1];
    phantom.sleep(200);
    phantom.render(output);
    phantom.exit();
}
```